# Android Room - Return Row from SELECT Query

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata

I'm using Android Room to build an offline database. I'm able to perform simple INSERT or DELETE queries but i'm having hard time figuring out how to perform a SELECT with parameters that returns a single row. This is my code right now:

users_details table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_details")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val userId: Int,
    var email : String,
    val userName: String = "NoName",
)
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE email =:email LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun findByEmail(email: String) : User
}
```

Repository:

```
class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {
    suspend fun findUserByEmail(email: String): User {
        return userDao.findByEmail(email)
   }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val user: LiveData<User>
        get() = _user

    fun findUserByEmail(email: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
                val userByEmail = repository.findUserByEmail(email)
                _user.value = userByEmail
                Log.d("ViewModel", _user.value.toString())  <--HERE LIVEDATA RESULTS UPDATED AND USER RESULTS LOADED FROM ROOM TABLE
            }
    }
}
```

UI Compose

```
@Composable
fun Screen(navController: NavController, UserViewModel : UserViewModel) {

//CODE FOR GOOGLE-SIGNIN - CODE OUTPUT is "username" and "useremail" in a user object


    //Support variable for observing LiveData in UserViewModel
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    //Manage next Navigation element based on/if the user is already recorded in Room DB
    user?.let {

        LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {

            navController.popBackStack()

            //Check if email used to log-in is already in Database
            val isUserInDatabase = mUserViewModel.readAllData.value?.
            find { user -> user.email == it.email }

            //If it doesn't exist in DB go to FirstLoginScreen to create user
            if (isUserInDatabase == null) {
                navController.navigate("firstlogin")
            }

            //If it exists load user details and continue to MainScreen
            else {
                mUserViewModel.findUserByEmail(it.email!!)
                mUserViewModel.user.observe(lifecycleOwner) {
                    navController.navigate("main")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I already read many similar posts but no one has been able to let me fully understand what is wrong.
I tried to use `LiveData<User>` too, but i'm surely doing it wrong, because i always get null data even if data in table exists (checked with `Log`)

EDIT: Thanks to  @CommonsWare comments i have been able to understand that the main issue was related to use these calls in the mainThread. I have been able to avoid crashes implementing `viewModelScope.launch()`. Unfortunately i am not still able to get the result i want. Code above is updated.

Comment: "checked with Log" -- have you looked in the actual database, such as by using the App Inspection tool in Android Studio?

Comment: No, i didn't until now because actually i didn't know of such tool for Room. I am still quite unexperienced. Btw, i just followed your suggestion and i confirm that the row i would like to extract is in the table.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your code, though I don't know that I have used `LIMIT 1` this way with Room. You might run some experiments, such as having a function returning `List<User>` without the `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Unfortunately i already tried the combinations you're proposing. I tried removing `LIMIT 1` from query, returning `List<User>`....nothing changes. App crashes when i call method `findUserByEmail` from `ViewModel`. I even tried to return LiveData<User> or LiveData<List<User>>, but i'm not really confident in the syntax i used and i'm not able to get anything. Can this be related to the use/not use of `suspend` and `viewModelScope.Dispatcher`?

Comment: With your current code, you may be doing the work on the main application thread, which Room will not like. We do not have access to your calling code. So, one possibility is that you are catching Room's main-application-thread exception, not logging it anywhere (so you do not realize that it is happening), and you are proceeding without a result (hence, `null`). FWIW, [this free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Room/) covers using Room from Kotlin with coroutines (and `LiveData`).

Comment: The calling code is a  `@Composable` function in a JetPack Compose project so the application-thread issue you highlighted could be the one i have to look for. I got a gist about how using co-routines in Room, i'll make some tests. Thanks for the book link!

Comment: Updated the code in the question with the @Compose UI caller. Your book has been unvaluable resource to understand some issue but i'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The issue was caused by the positioning of line:

`navController.popBackStack()`

The right position for this line is just before `navController.navigate("screen")`, like this:

```
user?.let {

        LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {

            //navController.popBackStack() //<- IN THIS POSITION CODE DOESN'T WORK!!!!

            //Check if email used to log-in is already in Database
            val isUserInDatabase = mUserViewModel.readAllData.value?.
            find { user -> user.email == it.email }

            //If it doesn't exist in DB go to FirstLoginScreen to create user
            if (isUserInDatabase == null) {
                navController.popBackStack() //<---HERE IS GOOD!
                navController.navigate("firstlogin")
            }

            //If it exists load user details and continue to MainScreen
            else {
                mUserViewModel.findUserByEmail(it.email!!)
                mUserViewModel.user.observe(lifecycleOwner) {
                    navController.popBackStack() //<---HERE IS GOOD!
                    navController.navigate("main")
                }
            }
        }
```

I still don't understand why the old code doesn't work. In particular i don't understand why the code below `popBackStack()` method runs normally (i.e. the `mUserViewModel.findUserByEmail(it.email!!)` is called) but i don't get `LiveData` updates. I hope expert community members have an explanation.